# BASE64 ECG Waveform plotting in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, binary, base64

I have the following data from an ECG in XML that has been encoded in base64. Original data in 16 bits signed 400 units per mV and 1 KHz sampling frequency. I've been trying to extract the binary data into mV data but I keep getting unexpected data. I'm not able to plot it with python.

I hope there's someone that can give me hand on how to get the correct numbers out of it. This is the data from one of the channels.

```
<CHANNEL
    OFFSET="0"
    BITS="16"
    FORMAT="SIGNED"
    UNITS_PER_MV="400"
    DURATION="10000"
    SAMPLE_FREQ="1000"
    NAME="II"
    ENCODING="BASE64"
    DATA="FwAbABwAGwAeABsAGgAZABkAGQAaABsAHAAeAB0AGwAeAB4AHgAeAB8AHgAg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"
  />
```

Comment: There isn't much information from the provider.  This is an ECG waveform encoded in Base64. As long as I can interpret is the voltage level of the waveform in 16 bits. I would expect to be int but I'm not completely sure. I've been using base64.b64decode(data) command to get the binary data. Then I'm pairing 2 bytes to form the 16 bits words. However, I'm getting noise in my decoded waveform. I don't know if it's that used the wrong command or wrong reconstruction format.

Comment: However, I'm thinking that this might be float instead. I'm a little bit stuck with struct. I don't understand very well how this can help me to parse the data.